# Can't delete file from sdcard

Tags: android, eclipse

i am using this code

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      File dir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp/MyFolder");
                       if (dir.isDirectory()) 
                       {
                           File file = new File(card.imagePath);
                           file.delete();
                       }
```

But it is not deleting file from the card. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about file path?

```
File file = new File(card.imagePath);

if(file.isExists()){
             file.delete();
             System.out.print("File exists and delete");
} else{
             System.out.print("File NOT exists");
}
```

ADD Persmissions ::

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

- Check if the file exists
- Check the file permissions, if you have the write permission on the file.

Comment: Also, use the proper `File` constructor instead of concatenation, and make sure you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.